# LibreOffice: using a dash as bullet automatically

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer, bullets

With OpenOffice, I could use a dash as a bullet. I started a new line with a dash, space, then some text, then enter. Magically, the dash would convert to a bullet list, indent, etc. When LibreOffice this doesn't work anymore. Old documents which have these dashed bullets still work, and copying and pasting works, but it doesn't work automatically anymore.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the **[`AutoCorrect Options`](https://help.libreoffice.org/swriter/CUI_HID_OFAPAGE_AUTOFORMAT_CLB?Language=en-US&System=WIN&Version=4.1#bm_id3150999)**:

1. In LibreOffice Writer, open menu `Tools`;
2. Select `AutoCorrect Options`.

In the following dialogue:

[image: LibreOffice Writer AutoCorrect Options]

you can toggle the option `Apply numbering - symbol:`.

The symbol at the right of the word `symbol:` shows the bullet type LO will insert instead of the dash you've entered. **EDIT:** To change the bullet symbol, do one of the following (after enabling the `apply numbering`option):

- double-click on the symbol;
- click on the `Edit` button at the lower left:

[image: LibreOffice Writer AutoCorrect Options 2]

The character map will appear, allowing to select a new bullet character.

Comment: Excellent! Double click the text and you can change the symbol. Thanks!

Comment: @rxt - you're right, i forgot to mention how to change the symbol. I'll add this to my answer. Happy to hear that it helped you :-) !