# Is there a way so bullets write in libreoffice open the same in Microsoft Office?

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, odt

I have an Open Document Text file write with LibreOffice when opened in Microsoft Word it appear very similar (which is normal). The only thing that is a little annoying are the list bullets.

In LibreOffice I have created the default list, simply pushed the list button. And the bullets appears as dots and in the second level they appear as a empty little circle. Then when opened in Microsoft Word (I think is Office 2013) the first level appear as circle with the number 10 inside and the second level as an arrow.

The arrow isn't very bad, but the number is a little confused because it give the idea that is a numbered list and something go wrong (because all have the number 10).

I used LibreOffice 4.1.3.2 to make the odt and opened it with Microsoft Word 2013.

I have found this link [Differences between the OpenDocument Text (.odt) format and the Word (.docx) format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/differences-between-the-opendocument-text-odt-format-and-the-word-docx-format-HA010355788.aspx) that explain the differences and it stated for bullets:

> Default bullets in OpenOffice change appearance when .odt file is opened in Word 2013.

So is something that is know by them. Still, I want to know if is some way to get the same (or similar) bullets in both text processors.

**Edit:** I have get access to an office 2013 and I have seen that default list bullets are show correctly but not others.

In the images bellow, the first list is a default one, the second is formatted with other bullets, the third is with images and the last is a numbered list.

This are a capture of the list in libre office:
[image]

And here the same file opened in Miscrosoft Word 2013:
[image]

Comment: No; Its a known issue; LibreOffice doesn't handle the bullets right and/or are using a different default bullet.

Comment: @Ramhound You found a bug or something about it officially?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is only half an answer...

This question relates to setting the bullet point character in LibreOffice.

[LibreOffice: using a dash as bullet automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/684885/libreoffice-using-a-dash-as-bullet-automatically?rq=1)

I don't know what the character code is for the character Microsoft Office uses as the bullet, but (perhaps) if you worked *that* answer using the MS character it would get you what you want.

Edit: Follow-on thought
If you look at the .doc file using a hex editor you should be able to identify the bullet character by finding the surrounding text.  And change them one by one or by mass-editing if you have a mind to.  Tiresome to have to do this on each document, so I hope you are able to get a full solution.

Comment: I think that you are right, is something about what char chosen by Microsoft for the ones in Libreoffice.

Answer (score 0):

What version of LibreOffice are you using? It could be a bug with 4.1 which would have been solved in 4.1.2.

http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/23556/problem-with-bullets-appearing-as-square-glyphs-when-imported-from-word-doc/

Comment: I have LibreOffice 4.1.3.2 so I think that this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using SoftMaker FreeOffice instead of LibreOffice, because it has a much better compatibility with Microsoft Office. It is full-fledged office suite, available free of charge for Linux and Windows (you get it here: freeoffice.com).

The included word processor FreeOffice TextMaker can open ODT faithfully, and if you create documents including bullets with FreeOffice TextMaker, save them as doc, and open them with Word 2013, the bullets will look like they should look.